# "Double quotes" are not displayed properly : Even in Fresh Installation

Tags: icons

I noticed this strange bug on Ubuntu.  When I open a terminal and select -> Edit-> Profile Preferences, I get the window as shown below **☟** . The double quotes are not being displayed properly, and I do not know why. Please help me to solve this bug.

[image]

**EDIT:**

- out put of `echo $LANG` : **`en_IN`**
- During The installation, I connect to internet and set my location to **Bangalore-ಬೆಂಗಳೂರು** (India)

**UPDATE :**

I noticed something even more weird, This happens to all the windows with **" "**,  but **NOT in FULL SCREEN** Mode

[image]

But when the **same** window is made fullscreen :

[image]

### Most Important:

- **YES!**, This Error Exists even in all the Virtual-Machines(Ubuntu) in Virtual-box (both host and VM)
- **NO!** This error does not happen when I boot from a LIVE-USB (Ubuntu)

#### No Luck with Fresh Installation:

With no other Options Left, I Completely removed my current 14.04 Ubuntu, Formatted my Hard disk and Installed **Ubuntu 15.10** , Installed Nothing on it - First thing I did is Check this Error. **YES!** But quite different this time
[image]

Comment: If this is a clean install of Ubuntu, and you did not modify any settings of the Gnome Terminal, then I would call this a bug, and should be reported as such.

Comment: what is your desktop environment?  what is the output of echo $LANG ? what system font are you using?

Comment: @joh Thanks for showing interest , I have Updated the question as you said :)

Comment: Works alright for me. Are you using a language input other than english ?

Comment: @Serg I am using English language. In Language support, In the language tab "Language for Menus and Windows" is **English (United States)** . But In 'Regional Formats' tab, 'Display numbers-dates-currency'is **English (India)**

Comment: Try altering the environment variable `LC_ALL=C` in terminal, and then try changing the title

Comment: @Serg I didn't fully understand what you are referring to.. could you please provide me some more explanation? :-)

Comment: @blade19899 Question Updated :-) Is this a bug? should I report it? But again, this does not happen on a **Live-USB**. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minor issue appears due to your regional language settings. When you switch the regional settings to English (United States), the double quotes are displayed correctly after logging out and back in. During the installation process you selected Bangalore as your location. That is the reason why it is displayed in the wrong way. You have to decide what is more important for you, living with this little minor issue and having your regional settings including the Indian currency set in the correct way, or having set and using the foreign language English as default language.

You may want to consider to file a bug report on Launchpad for getting this solved in the future editions of Ubuntu. Maybe other users are annoyed about this issue as well and confirm the bug.

Here you find the information you need, how to report bugs on Launchpad : [How to report bugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)

Comment: Thank you :) this solved my problem. And also... I managed to get both 'Indian' and 'Double-quotes' properly by setting my location to "kolkata" (another place in India). I think  "Bangalore-ಬೆಂಗಳೂರು" was the problem. Your answer helped me to solve this :)